# How to copy a product's taxons from one product to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I need to copy taxons from one product to another in Spree (v 2.2) with a single command line.

A product can have many taxons, so it's really just a question of copying the has_many association from one object to another, I guess.

This is a terrible sudo-code idea of how the logic makes sense to me:

```
@product_to_copy_taxons_from = Spree::Product.find(params[:id])

@product_to_copy_taxons_to = @current_product.update_attributes! for taxon_ids: all @product_to_copy_taxons_from.ids
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you do something like `@current_product.taxons << @product_to_copy_taxons_from.taxons`?

Comment: Well...I had no idea that `<<` was just a powerhouse of association copying.  That's exactly it...thanks.

Comment: Great. Added as answer with reference to the guides. Please upvote/accept as you like and for future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is something like:

```
@current_product.taxons << @product_to_copy_taxons_from.taxons
```

You can find the methods (including `:<<`) added by the `has_many` association in [the guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many).